# How to add a HTML page to a self host docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

In my server, I have deployed a custom docker registry with [Docker Registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry).

So commands below works (assuming the host is `registry.example.com`):

```sh
docker pull alpine
docker tag alpine registry.example.com/alpine
docker push registry.example.com/alpine

docker system prune -af # just clean up

docker pull registry.example.com/alpine # It works!
```

But then, when I navigate to `registry.example.com` on a browser, it shows a completely blank page (HTTP returns empty).

I would like to do something similar to [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/).

How can I add a custom HTML page, so that when navigating to `registry.example.com` it will return some HTML instead of an empty body? (I don't need a backend server for registration or database. Just a simple HTML document will suffice.)

Do I need to modify some files or config in `/var/lib/registry`?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

on the Docker documentation, https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/

i was trying to find a setting to have a custom webpage, i could not find a setting for this. The docker hub probably has a page and retrieves the data from the Docker API

Answer (score 0):

Docker HUB != Docker Registry
because
Docker HUB > Docker Registry

You need to create own RestAPI or WEB service that will call docker via CLI/docker internal API and response JSON data/HTML pages.

If you want to use ready solution, I recommend [portainer](https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/registries/connect/) as docker WebUI